# How to fix macOS 12.3 Finder is unable to reliably copy large files to SMB shares

Tags: finder, network, sharing, smb, monterey

About when macOS 12.3 shipped I am unable to reliably copy files to SMB shares with the Finder with an M1 Max MBP. The copied files on the share are corrupted (the share has not been updated in months and works just fine). Checking the contents, large sections are all zeros.

At first I assumed it was the share and I assumed it was a bad hard drive. I went out and bought a new hard drive but had the same issue. Large files copied get corrupted.

Then I tested other device and methods. If I copy via the Terminal (`cp srcfile /Volumes/ShareName/dstfile`) everything is fine. I've tried copying via other non-macOS devices as well as a macOS 11.6.4 MBP and they are all able to copy fine too.

Is this a known problem? Is there a fix? An SMB setting?

Note: I also noticed copying from the old 2014 MacOS 11.6.4 MBP is 1.5x to 2x faster than the 2021 M1 Max 12.3 MBP even though the new MBP is 2 meters from the WiFi AP and the old one is 10 meters away in another room. Not sure if that suggests something.

Comment: What device and OS is doing the sharing?

Comment: I just wanted to reply to say you aren't crazy. This is happening to me too, I'm glad you posted this. I for one am going to stop using SMB from a MacOS client and switch to scp/sftp.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. I thought I was going crazy. I hope someone finds a fix for this.

Comment: I just ran across this bug! We were able to work around it by using `rsync` instead of `cp` - that worked fine - but wow, did I feel like I was going insane.

Comment: I don't think this is limited to the M1s. I have an Early 2014 MacBook Air running BigSur 11.7.4. I regularly download "large files" from torrents to the MacBook and then copy the files over WiFi to SMB shares on my Synology box. I recently noticed that several large files I had transferred were corrupted, and even though they had shown 100% downloaded on the MacBook, a "recheck" in QBittorrent showed the same files were less than 100% after being moved to the SMB shares. I went back and rechecked other files that I had downloaded over the years, and it seems this has been an ongoing problem.

Comment: I've changed the settings on my Synology box to require SMB2 at a minimum instead of SMB1.  I'll see if that makes any difference going forward.  Maybe I'll have to up the minimum to SMB2 w/ large MTU or even SMB3.